# rearrange xml elements and rename tags

Tags: xml

I have an xml where all the data is in.
But it is in the wrong order and with the wrong tags.

How can i convert the input-file to become like the output-file below?

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<orders>
  <order>
    <id>7140930</id>
    <status>processing_awaiting_shipment</status>
    <addressShippingCompany>false</addressShippingCompany>
    <addressShippingName>name</addressShippingName>
    <addressShippingStreet>street</addressShippingStreet>
    <addressShippingStreet2/>
    <addressShippingNumber>2</addressShippingNumber>
    <addressShippingExtension/>
    <addressShippingZipcode>1111</addressShippingZipcode>
    <addressShippingCity>city</addressShippingCity>
    <addressShippingRegion/>
    <addressShippingCountry>
      <id>21</id>
      <code>be</code>
      <code3>bel</code3>
      <title>Belgium</title>
    </addressShippingCountry>
  </order>
</orders>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NAVIPWMS>
  <IDENTIFICATION>
    <PROCESSTYPE>OUTBOUNDORDER</PROCESSTYPE>
  </IDENTIFICATION>
  <HEADER>
    <DATE>20150126</DATE>
    <CUSTNOEXT>K00020</CUSTNOEXT>
    <ORDTYPE>UIT</ORDTYPE>
    <PERSONALMSG>
      <LINE></LINE>
    </PERSONALMSG>
    <SENDERCOMMENT></SENDERCOMMENT>
    <ADDRESSES>
      <ADDRESS>
        <ADDRTYPE>UNLOADING</ADDRTYPE>
        <ADDRCODE></ADDRCODE>
        <ADDRNAME>name</ADDRNAME>
        <ADDRESS1>street + number</ADDRESS1>
        <ADDRESS2></ADDRESS2>
        <HOUSENO></HOUSENO>
        <CNTRY>DEU</CNTRY>
        <CITY>Essen</CITY>
        <POSTC>45329</POSTC>
        <REF>21635</REF>
        <CONTACT>contactinfo</CONTACT>
        <PHONE>0000</PHONE>
        <EMAIL></EMAIL>
      </ADDRESS>
    </ADDRESSES>
  </HEADER>
</NAVIPWMS>
```

I want to get `<addressShippingName>` filled in in the right output-tag (`<ADDRNAME>`)
And merge the `<addressShippingStreet>` and `<addressShippingNumber>` and fill it in `<ADDRESS1>`

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far? If you want to receive help you need to present us with a tangible point where you are failing. This is not a site to ask someone to implement things for you.

Comment: @Cu3PO42, i tried to use bash, but with xmlstartlet i get multiple values (of the next node) back.
So i don't think thats the right way

xmlstarlet sel -t -m "orders" -m "order" -v "id" < orders.xml